# Table well displayed in html but not in the pdf generated with mpdf

Tags: php, html, mpdf

I am trying to generate a PDF in PHP using mPDF.
A part of my document must be like this: [image]
<sub>(source: [cloudandfun.com](http://cloudandfun.com/Capture.PNG))</sub>

So I wrote for the HTML:

```
<table style = "width:100%">
<tr>
    <td>Appellation <br>(par ordre de préférence)</td>
    <td style = "border:0px;">
        <table style = "width:100%; border:0px;">
            <tr style = "border:0px;"><th style = "border:0px;">Abréviation (S’il y a lieu)</th></tr>
        </table>
        <table style = "width:100%;border:0px;">
            <tr style = " border:0px;">
                <td style = "width:33%;border-bottom:0px;border-left:0px;">Abréviation</td>
                <td style = "width:33%;border-bottom:0px;border-left:0px;">Facultative</td>
                <td style = "width:33%;border-bottom:0px;border-left:0px;border-right:0px;">Obligatoire</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>1.</td>
    <td>
        <table style = "width:100%;border:0px;">
            <tr style = " border:0px;">
                <td style = "width:33%;border-bottom:0px;border-left:0px;border-top:0px;">--</td>
                <td style = "width:33%;border-bottom:0px;border-left:0px;border-top:0px;">--</td>
                <td style = "width:33%;border:0px;">--</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2.</td>
    <td>
        <table style = "width:100%;border:0px;">
            <tr style = " border:0px;">
                <td style = "width:33%;border-bottom:0px;border-left:0px;border-top:0px;">--</td>
                <td style = "width:33%;border-bottom:0px;border-left:0px;border-top:0px;">--</td>
                <td style = "width:33%;border:0px;">--</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
```

My CSS:

```
th,td,tr {
  border:1px solid black;
  border-collapse:collapse;
}

table {
  border:2px solid black;
  border-collapse:collapse;
}

td {
  font-family:Arial;
  font-size:11px;
}
```

In the html page, it works great, but when the pdf is generated, it appears like this: [image]
<sub>(source: [cloudandfun.com](http://cloudandfun.com/Capture1.PNG))</sub>

Does anyone have a solution for that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try putting the style information into a css sheet attached to the page then try print again, see if that helps. MPDF might have trouble reading `style = "width:33%;border:0px;` and prefer it in a different format. that's my guess anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I put that css in a css sheet, and called it in mpdf like $stylesheet = file_get_contents('cn.css');
$mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet,1); but this doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: did you try `$stylesheet = '<style>'.file_get_contents('cn.css').'</style>';` you have to tell mdpf that this is css

Comment: Yes I did, for mpdf, the parameter 1 means that's it's a css, I have also tried with <style></style> like you said. when I add another style it's concidered, so I think this isn't the problem

Comment: hmmm, could you post the mpdf code ?

Comment: You can download it on: http://mpdf1.com/repos/MPDF57.zip

Comment: no I meant `$mpdf->WriteHTML` bit

Comment: <?php require_once('MPDF/mpdf.php');
$mpdf = new mPDF('ar','A4');
$stylesheet = file_get_contents('cn.css');
$mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet,1);
$entete = file_get_contents("entete.html");
$mpdf->SetHTMLHeader($entete);
$cnhtml = file_get_contents("cn.html");
$mpdf->WriteHTML($cnhtml);
$mpdf->Output();
exit;
?>

Comment: I've got the solution, instead of giving % I gave the width with px and it worked.
Conclusion: mPDF doesn't support % (width:33%; for my example) but supports px (width:100px; for my example). ;) ;)

Comment: Can you write your solution as an answer so others with the same problem as you will know how you solved it?

Comment: The question images aren't online anymore, but I just had a similar bug when trying to use mpdf with tables. Take care with big tables, mpdf will try by default to fit a table in a page (https://mpdf.github.io/paging/page-breaks.html#tables).
So what I suggest is to do not use table inside another table, it fixed my problem. PS: mpdf, at least 6.1 that I am using, support width with %

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've got the solution, instead of giving % I gave the width with px and it worked.
Conclusion: mPDF doesn't support % (width:33%; for my example) but supports px (width:100px; for my example). ;) ;)